gganimate when increasing resolution, height of the chart changes
I've been trying to build a simple gganimate and I need it to be of high quality.
When increasing the resolution I see that the chart is changing its size completely and looks different, much better.
But size increases and I don't understand why.
   library(ggplot2)
   library(gganimate)
   
   anim <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
     geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Month))) +
     transition_time(Day) + 
     enter_fade() +
     exit_fade()
   
   animate(anim, renderer = av_renderer('1.mp4'), 
           duration = 20,
           width = 1920, height = 1080,  fps = 25)
   
   animate(anim, renderer = av_renderer('2.mp4'), 
           duration = 20,
           width = 1920, height = 1080, res = 100, fps = 25)
   
   animate(anim, renderer = av_renderer('3.mp4'), 
           duration = 20,
           width = 1920, height = 1080, res = 300, fps = 25)

Is the an option to increase the resolution while keeping the same width and height?
And how am I supposed to pick the correct resolution depending on the size of the plot?
Thank you for the support

A helpful tutorial on ggplot2 size vs. resolution: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/.  You might also look at the camcorder package as a tool try out various size / resolution settings with a non-animated version (e.g. filter to just one Day).
